# Is it possible to add a variable to an image filename?

Tags: javascript, html

Noob here. It’s probably not even possible, but I would like something like this:

$variable=[today’s date]

img src=“0001.jpg?$variable”

Explanation: my homepage has a lot of images that i often change. But filenames stay the same, so iPhones don’t refresh them, but use old cached images. Adding a new filename extension every day should ensure that iPhones load the new images.

I’m using Noteoad to write my homepage, so changing all the filename extensions manually would take hours.

Tried google, but apparently variables are not possible in HTML, so…

Comment: If you're writing your page directly in HTML and uploading it to a server, you'll need to use client-side javascript to do this.

Comment: “ I’m using Noteoad to write my homepage, so changing all the filename extensions manually would take hours” — Fix *that* instead of trying to deal with it client-side. Get yourself a tool chain that processes your image URLs at build time (e.g. by adding a MD5sum of the latest version of the image to the URLs).

Comment: Isn't this an issue with cache management that could be corrected by setting appropriate cache headers on the image's response? Either no-cache or a shorter period, like 1 hour or 12 hours.

Comment: @ejner please do not forget, to mark answeres that solved your problem as 'accepted' (Checkmark)

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this approach with javascript. The code should be put in a script-tag as element after the body-tag, so all image-tags are rendered before the script starts running.

In your page add the script tag like this:

```
<html>
   <body>
     ...your stuff
   </body>
   <script>
       allImages = document.getElementsByTagName('img')
       allImagesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(allImages);
       urlParam = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);
       for(i=0; i<allImagesArray.length; i++){
          allImagesArray[i].setAttribute('src', allImagesArray[i].src+'?'+urlParam)
       };
   </script>
</html>
```

Explanation:

```
// This will collect all of the images by their tag (img)
// and assign the result to the variable allImages

allImages = document.getElementsByTagName('img')

// 'allImages' now contains something called 'HTMLCollection'
// and here we convert it to an 'Array'

allImagesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(allImages);

// Get the date today (will only change every 24 hours!)

urlParam = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);

// Now we iterate over each element in the 'allImagesArray'
// and add the current date to the url in every images src-attribute

for(i=0; i<allImagesArray.length; i++){
    allImagesArray[i].setAttribute('src', allImagesArray[i].src+'?'+urlParam)
};
```

However this approach is very simple and has its downsides. And I am not sure it will work in every targeted browser.

**Also when you uploaded new images you will have to wait till the next day to see them when you are testing.
If you want to see the changes immediately you have to change the urlParam to the value of Date.now() this will change every reload because it returns current milliseconds (microtime).**

Just change the line where the urlParam is initialized like this:

```
urlParam = Date.now()
```

that would look like this

```
<html>
   <body>
     ...your stuff
   </body>
   <script>
       allImages = document.getElementsByTagName('img')
       allImagesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(allImages);
       urlParam = Date.now();
       for(i=0; i<allImagesArray.length; i++){
          allImagesArray[i].setAttribute('src', allImagesArray[i].src+'?'+urlParam)
       };
   </script>
</html>
```

I guess that's it. Let me know if you have any questions.

Cheers

Phil

Comment: Actually `Date.now()` returns the current millisecond, I think the OP wants to format the current date and return a specific part (like day, hour, etc.)

Comment: @ParkingMaster - as far as I can tell from the question Ejner wants to keep the filenames in the html and just overwrite the corresponding files on the server, wich in turn raises the problem, that browsers might use the cached files and not new ones. The code provided will make the browser reload the files on every page-reload because the src-attribute changed.

Comment: @ParkingMaster - I think you are right, though. I changed the answere accordingly. Cheers.

Comment: Edited to avoid the use of Array.map() for older browsers

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.

Comment: I tried inserting your script, but I still see the old cached images.

Comment: @ejner thats probably because it will only change every 24 hours. If you want to see the changes immediately Just change the line where the urlParam is initialized like this:

urlParam = Date.now()

(Thats described in the answere, too - if read the explanation part)

If you have any more questions please post your code

Comment: @ejner added example for using microtime below.

Comment: THANK YOU! I missed that, but now it’s working perfectly! I will be using your code snippet from now on forward…

Comment: You are very welcome. Have fun.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need to update the variable at all, if a browser sees there is a variable it will reload the image.

```
<img src=“0001.jpg?v=1”/>
```

should do it.

Comment: You misunderstand how cache busting URLs work. It isn’t that a query string tells the browser not to cache the image, it is that changing the query string to be a different value changes the URL to a new URL … which the browser hasn’t cached the response for already.